# Capture successfully inserted records into array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo

I am using PDO to insert records from one table into another.

I'm trying to capture the records that were successfully inserted into the other table, while also capturing the records that might have failed to insert.

```
<?php
  $checkcontainer = $_POST['checkcontainer'];
  $checkscac = $_POST['checkscac'];
  $comment = $_POST['comment'];
  $time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

  $containerSuccess = array();
  $containerFail = array();

  $count = count($checkcontainer);

  for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++)
  {
    $container = $checkcontainer[$i];
    $scac = $checkscac[$i];

    $insert = $dbc->prepare("INSERT IGNORE INTO trucker_edi_comms (container, scac, fac_comments, fac_datestamp) VALUES (:ucont,:uscac,:ucomm,:utime);");

    $insert->execute([
        'ucont' => $container,
        'uscac' => $scac, 
        'ucomm' => $comment,
        'utime' => $time
    ]);

    if($insert)
    {
        $containerSuccess = $container;
        //echo "containers saved: " . $containerSuccess;
    }
    else
    {
        $containerFail = $container;
        //echo "containers failed: " . $containerFail;
    }
  }

  echo "containers saved: " . $containerSuccess;
?>
```

The INSERT statement works.  I can also set the $containerSuccess array to $container.  If 3 containers are successfully inserted, the output from inside the FOR loop looks like this:

```
containers saved: TEST123456789containers saved: TEST98642357containers saved: TEST65897531
```

But I need to be able to echo $containerSuccess outside of the FOR loop.  Currently, the output looks like this:

```
containers saved: TEST65897531
```

I'm only able to grab the last container that was saved.

I need to echo out all of the containers outside of the FOR loop to display to the user.

How can I make this happen?

Comment: What do you think `if($insert)` is doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example was trying to populate a declared array with a string, so you were on the right track concerning the variable type.  You can populate an array for outputting the saved/failed containers after the loop completes, and if you want it to output on one line, use [implode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) for the output:

```
<?php
  $checkcontainer = $_POST['checkcontainer'];
  $checkscac = $_POST['checkscac'];
  $comment = $_POST['comment'];
  $time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

  $containerSuccess = array();
  $containerFail = array();

  $count = count($checkcontainer);

  for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++)
  {
    $container = $checkcontainer[$i];
    $scac = $checkscac[$i];

    $insert = $dbc->prepare("INSERT IGNORE INTO trucker_edi_comms (container, scac, fac_comments, fac_datestamp) VALUES (:ucont,:uscac,:ucomm,:utime);");

    $insert->execute([
        'ucont' => $container,
        'uscac' => $scac, 
        'ucomm' => $comment,
        'utime' => $time
    ]);

    if($insert)
        $containerSuccess[] = $container;
    else
        $containerFail[] = $container;

  }

  echo "containers saved: " . implode(', ', $containerSuccess);
  echo "containers failed: " . implode(', ', $containerFail);

?>
```

Comment: Wow... I completely forgot about the brackets.  SMH.  Thank you, sir.  This is what worked.  I will mark this as complete.